# How to use "resulting"?

Tags: grammar

My teacher gave me an error identification question, which is : 
"An itch resulting when a nerve that can carry pain is only slightly stimulated".
I have a feeling the word "resulting" is a fault but don't know how to use it properly or if it needs change. Please help me.

Comment: Have you completed the assignment and handed it in already?

Comment: Nope, but I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Resulting* needs to be changed to *results*, because the verb should agree with the noun *itch*, which is singular, and the tense should be present, since the sentence is stating a generally true fact.

Comment: But *resulting* can also be correct if the whole thing were to become a dependent clause:  "An itch resulting [that results] when a nerve that can carry pain is only slightly stimulated, is different than a *phantom itch* experienced by some amputees."

Comment: True, but I was just working with what he had in the sentence.

Comment: Right so the "error in the statement" is either: 1. *resulting* should be *results* or 2. The last half of the sentence is missing.

Comment: Thanks Jim and Nick. It helps! At first  I thought result is a transitive verb but it seems the word is both transitive and intransitive, isn't it?

Comment: I believe result can only be intransitive, but you can make it seem like it's transitive if you expand it to *results in [something]*